# Required fields during serialization in Jackson

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I have multiple REST endpoints that accept the same Java object and I'm looking for a clean approach to a server side data validation on this object. In each API call, there are varying field requirements with some overlap.

I want the initial data validation to verify if fields are empty / null and figured Jackson would be a great place to start. I'm hoping there is some combination of `@JsonView` and `@JsonProperty(required=true)` that could be used but I'm not seeing anything.

If this isn't possible in Jackson, I already know how I will approach this using reflection. I'm just hoping to save some time. Also willing to implement existing, well-documented libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring validation. Create your own [SmartValidator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/SmartValidator.html) and then use [@Validated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) annotation to specify its behaviour in a particular case.